# OnQueryTextListener runs automatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have a `TabLayout` in `MainActivity`. and return a `Fragment` for each tab of `TabLayout`. in one of my `Fragments` I have a `SearchView`. when I open tab of this `Fragment`, The following things will happen:

first open:
`Toast` is not shown.

**second open:
`Toast` shown.** *Why????*

third and more open:
`Toast` is not shown.

my `onCreateView()` method of `Fragment`:

```
private View root = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (root != null) {
            return root;
        }

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) root.findViewById(R.id.searchView);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text changed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
```

Comment: do not use `Toast` for debugging purposes, use `Log.d` instead

Comment: @pskink OK. thank you. but the result did not change.

Comment: how many times is `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener` called? what do you mean by `first open`, `second open` etc?

Comment: @pskink Sorry. I edited the title. my problem is: why `onQueryTextChange` runs for second time I open the tab?

Comment: @pskink one time I set it. first open means When I clicked on this `Fragment` tab on `MainActivity` for first time. and etc.

Comment: just log `Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange: [" + newText + "]");` what do you see?

Comment: @pskink result: `onQueryTextChange: []`.

Comment: so you can skip empty text, cant you?

Comment: @pskink I can skip `if (!searchView.hasFocus())`. thanks.

Comment: no: `TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str)`